# Using vba with selenium how to get a specific cell in a table and then click on it

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to access a table on a webpage and within the table trying to click on that cell.

the cell I am trying to reach has an td id="flowTile_6". Highlight it below.

I have tried various means

such as

```
ch.FindElementByXPath("//table[@id="mainFlow"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[15]").Click
```

this will error out.

and trying to loop through in a for each to get to it, I have no success.

```
Option Explicit

Private ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub test()

    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
    Dim ResultSections As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ResultSection As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim TableByTag As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim tr, c, r, td, li, cc, t
    
   
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.Start baseUrl:=""
    ch.Get "/"
    

    
    
   ' ch.FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click
   


       'Set TableByTag = ch.FindElementByTag("table")
       'ch.FindElementByXPath("//table[@id="mainFlow"/tbody/tr[7]/td[15]").Click
       
       
       For Each li In ch.FindElementById("mainFlow")
            cc = 1
        For Each t In li.FindElementsByTag("li")
            ch.FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click
            cc = cc + 1
        Next t
        Next li
      
End Sub
```

html

```
<div class="background">
<div class="holder">
<table class="flow" id="mainFlow" style="display: table;">
<tbody>
<tr class="collapsible" id="flowHeader1_text" isasection="true" onclick="doExpandCollapse(this)">
►<td colspan="25">...</td>
</tr>
<tr id="flowHeader1_underline">
<td colspan="25">
<div class="flowHeaderUnderline"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="flowHeader1_placeholder" class="sectionAnimationPlaceHolder">
<td colspan="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">...</tr> == $0
<tr id="row2" class="narrowSpacer">...</tr>
►<tr id="row3" class="narrowSpacer">...</tr>
<<tr id="row4">
<td class="a Em"X/td>
<td class="b Em"x/td>
<td class="a Em"></td>
<td class="d Em"x/td>
►<td id="flowTile_4" class="e item enabled hasIcon" role="link" aria-labelledby="tileDescription_4" havebox="true" formid="" tiletext="Supply/Demand Inquiry" appid="" version="" onclick
script:runApp (', '', '')" onmouseover="javascrpt: startHoverTimer(this);" onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybe End HoverMode (this);">...</td>
<td class="a Em"X</td>
<td class="b Em"X/td>
<td class="a Em"X/td>
<td class="d Em"x/td>
►<td id="flowTile_5" class="e item enabled hasIcon" role="link" aria-labelledby="tileDescription_5" havebox="true" formid="" tiletext="Item Availability" appid="" version="" onclick="
ript:runpp('', '', '')" onmouseover="javascrpt:startHoverTimer(this);" onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybe EndHoverMode(this);">.</td>
<td class="a Em"X/td>
<td class="b Em"></td>
<td class="a Em">/td>
<td class="d Em"X/td>

**<<td id="flowTile_6" class="e item enabled hasIcon" role="link" aria-labelledby="tileDescription_6" havebox="true" formid="W41016" tiletext="Item Master Inquiry" appid="" version="" onclick="
ript:runApp('', '','')" onmouseover="javascrpt:startHoverTimer(this);" onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybeEndHoverMode (this);">
<div class="relativeWrapper">
<img id="flowTileIconImg_6" size="medium" src="/ide/share/images/ideicons/supply chain mntn medium.png" autoreplace="true">**

<div>
<div class="wlTileDesciption" id="tileDescription_6">Item Master Inquiry</div> == $0
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td class="a Em"X/td>
<td class="b Em"></td>
<td class="a Em"X/td>
<td class="d Em"x/td>
><td id="flowTile_7" class="e item enabled hasIcon" role="link" aria-labelledby="tileDescription_7" havebox="true" formid="W302016" tiletext="Single Level Where Used" appid="" version="" onclick=
"javascript:runpp ("', '', ')" onmouseover="javascrpt:startHoverTimer(this);" onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybe EndHoverMode(this);">.</td>
<td class="a Em"x/td>
<td class="b Em"></td>
<td class="a Em"x/td>
<td class="d Em"X/td>
<td class="e Em"X/td>
</tr>
><tr id="rows" class="narrowSpacer">...</tr>
><tr id="row6" class="narrowSpacer">.</tr>
</tbody>
</table
</div>
远。
```

---

this is what i am trying to get to within the table

```
<<td id="flowTile_6" class="e item enabled hasIcon" role="link" aria-labelledby="tileDescription_6" havebox="true" formid="W41016" tiletext="Item Master Inquiry" appid="" version="" onclick="
ript:runpp('', '','')" onmouseover="javascrpt:startHoverTimer(this);" onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybeEndHoverMode (this);">
<div class="relativeWrapper">
<img id="flowTileIconImg_6" size="medium" src="/ide/share/images/ideicons/supply chain mntn medium.png" autoreplace="true">
```

Comment: ById will return a single element so you can't For Each over. Also, why not use that id then within ById and click? Otherwise, use the ExecuteScript method to call the associated onclick `ript:runE1App('P4101', 'W4101E','PSA0001')`

Comment: when I do try to just use the id and click,  it will say "element not found".

I will give the second method a try.

Comment: Is the element wrapped in a `frame`/`iframe` tag?

Comment: Yes, the table is within two nested  iframes.

Comment: @QHarr I am not understanding the ````ript:runE1App('P4101', 'W4101E','PSA0001')````
method or how to use it. Is that javaScript?

Comment: didn't know about Iframes. spent  some time learning. 
I have tried this:

````With ch
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
        .FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click
    End With
````
It will error out on the second swtichtoframe and say "no suchelementError"

Comment: @RaymondWu forgot to tag

Comment: Without visual of the html, not sure what to advise.. (Note: I'm not familiar with selenium but the concept should be similar..), can you edit your question and include the rest of the html including the iframes? @Red

Comment: ok, using the iframe id names I was able to get to the correct html path, Still not sure why the above just using the switch with switch by tag will not work 
 ````With ch
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("e1menuAppIframe", timeout:=10000)
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("wcFrame0", timeout:=10000)
        
        Set ResultSections = .FindElementsByClass("flow")
        
       For Each ResultSection In ResultSections
       
            Debug.Print ResultSection.Text
               
    Next ResultSection ````
@RaymondWu

Comment: this will print out the correct path of above html. It will print out the text of the cells of the table

However, if I use  ````.FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click````  or use the xpath above it still wont work and say not found

Comment: @Red Where did you use `.FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click`?  After the loop?

Comment: @RaymondWu I think it was saying element not found, because of page load delay. I ran it again with .FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click and it worked.

Comment: In this case, do a while loop that checks that `flowTile_6` exist then do the click after. I'm not that familiar with selenium syntax so can't help you there but in xmlhttp that would be something like `Do While .FindElementById("flowTile_6") Is Nothing: DoEvents: Wend`

Comment: VBA, wtf?!!!! Why isn't it dead already?

Comment: @jeribeb because of excel

Comment: selenium in evel, what a big brain case do we have out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was nested in two iframes.

was able to solve by:

```
With ch
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("e1menuAppIframe", timeout:=10000)
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("wcFrame0", timeout:=10000)
        
        Set ResultSections = .FindElementsByClass("flow")
        
       For Each ResultSection In ResultSections
        
        .FindElementById("flowTile_6").Click
    Next ResultSection
        
End With
```

Comment: @RaymondWu for credit of pointing to the correct path to solve.

Comment: I dont think you actually need the `For` loop and `ResultSections`, you can do the click right after you switch to the 2nd iframe. (After implementing the `While` loop as mentioned in my comment above to check for existance for `flowTile_6`) @Red

Comment: @RaymondWu You are right. There is no need for the For loop. I ran down the rabbit hole further to debug when it was saying not found. I think it was due to page not loading in.